# Give a specific example to show that $\mathbb Z_{2}$ × $S_{4}$ is not abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

Give a specific example to show that $\mathbb Z_{2}$ × $S_{4}$ is not abelian.

I know that $S_{4}$ is not abelian and therefore $\mathbb Z_{2}$ × $S_{4}$ is not abelian. I'm not sure how to show this with with an example, though. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Let $a,b$ be two non-commuting elements in $S_4$. Then, $\{0\} \times a$ and $\{0\} \times b$ are two non-commuting elements.

Comment: The same is true in general for any product of groups. If at least one group in the product is nonabelian, then the product is nonabelian. Use the same reasoning suggested by @N.H. above. The product needn't be finite. +1 for N.H.

Comment: Dear @N.H. : please consider making that a hint-solution. Here we consider high quality hints as solution material, depending on the question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice ! I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : Assume $a,b$ are non-commuting elements of $S_4$. What can you say about the elements $\{0\} \times a$ and $\{0 \} \times b$ ? Remember how is defined the group law on the product.

As @MPW said, the same argument works for a product $\prod_{a \in A}G_a$ of groups, when only one group is non-abelian.

Answer (score 2):

If $H$ is any group then you can think of a group $G$ as a subgroup of $H \times G$ by the mapping $x\mapsto (0,x)$.